# HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR Not working on mobile network .Is there any solution? for getting City name based on IP

Tags: c#, geolocation, ip, city

I have tried:

`Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]`,

`Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]`,

`Request.UserHostAddress;`

And used: `http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key={0}&ip={1}&format=json`

for getting the City Name.

and published the code . Its working well on PC but on mobile networks its not showing any...Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: Is the IP correct?

Comment: Do you get the right IP address when using mobile? Try to print out all the 3 variables and see.

Comment: Yeah I have checked in the mobile- Its showing my mobile network provider's city as network IP but not exactly where I am now.